# How can I display KeyCode and KeyData for lowercase letters in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, keydown

I'm trying to show informations on the Keyboard Keys pressed.
This code displays the Uppercase letters correctly, but the Uppercase information is shown also when a lowercase letter is pressed.

How can I solve this problem?
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public partial class keyDemo : Form
{
    private void keyDemo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        charLabel.Text = $"Key pressed: {e.KeyChar}";
    }

    private void keyDemo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keyInfoLabel.Text =
            $"Alt: {(e.Alt ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"Shift: {(e.Shift ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"Ctrl: {(e.Control ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"KeyCode: {e.KeyCode}\n" +
            $"KeyData: {e.KeyData}\n" +
            $"KeyValue: {e.KeyValue}";
    }

    private void keyDemo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        charLabel.Text = "";
        keyInfoLabel.Text = "";
    }
}
```

[image: it shows uppercase info but the pressed key is lowercase]

Comment: As you can see, `Keys.[Key]` doesn't have lowercase letters. The Upper/Lower case is determined by the state of Shift and/or CapsLock.

Comment: As you also noticed, `KeyPressEventArgs` returns an already processed value for the letters `Keys`, including the lowercase representation.

Comment: The KeyDown and KeyUp events provide the *virtual* keycode.  it is the same anywhere in the world and matches the Keys enum type.  What *character* they produce, if any, depends on the active keyboard layout and the state of the modifier keys.  Like Shift, Ctrl, Alt.  Extra complications for keyboards that have an AltGr key.  You know what that character is going to be, the KeyPress event delivers it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that `KeyEventArgs` returns details of a key, not a character. (The capital and lowercase letters use the same key.)
Some keys don't produce characters (e.g. Shift, F-keys), some produce non-printable characters (e.g. Tab, Escape) and the character produced by a certain keystroke depends on  on your keyboard layout.

If you want the character, you should probably be using the `KeyPress` rather than `KeyDown` event.

But if you want to do it:

As @PrinceOfRavens says, you'd have to check the state of the Caps Lock key.

You can do it like this, but this still doesn't handle keys other than letters, and doesn't handle Alt Gr (for accented letters). To fully convert a keystroke to a character, you'd have to convert both `Keys.Add` (numeric keypad '+') and Shift '=' on most keyboards to "+", and Shift '1' usually to "!" (depending on your keyboard layout).

You could extend it by replacing the `return null` in `KeyToLetter`, **but this is NOT the recommended way to get a character typed**.

(I've added two items to the output.)

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;   // for GetKeyState

    ...


    private void keyDemo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keyInfoLabel.Text =
            $"Alt: {(e.Alt ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"Shift: {(e.Shift ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"Ctrl: {(e.Control ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"KeyCode: {e.KeyCode}\n" +
            $"KeyData: {e.KeyData}\n" +
            $"KeyValue: {e.KeyValue}\n" +
            $"CapsLock: {(CapsLockState ? "Yes" : "No")}\n" +
            $"Letter: {KeyToLetter(e.KeyData, CapsLockState)}";
    }

    // Import the DLL to use a Win32 API call.
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate
    // If using WPF, you could use Keyboard.IsKeyDown :
    //  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(Keys nVirtKey);

    /// <summary>
    /// true if Caps Lock is on, otherwise false.
    /// </summary>
    public bool CapsLockState 
        => (GetKeyState(Keys.CapsLock) & 1) == 1;

    /// <summary/>
    /// <param name="key">A base key (no modifiers).</param>
    /// <returns>true if and only if the given key represents a letter.</returns>
    public static bool IsLetterKey(Keys key)
        => key >= Keys.A && key <= Keys.Z;

    /// <summary>
    /// Given a keystroke that produces a letter, this returns the letter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="capsLockState"></param>
    /// <returns>the letter, or null if the given keystroke does not produce a letter.</returns>
    public static char? KeyToLetter(Keys key, bool capsLockState)
    {
        Keys baseKey = key & ~Keys.Modifiers;  // remove modifier keys
        if (IsLetterKey(baseKey) && !key.HasFlag(Keys.Control))    // if a letter
        {
            bool shiftPressed = key.HasFlag(Keys.Shift);   // check whether Shift was pressed
            bool capital = capsLockState ^ shiftPressed;   // if it should be capital
            if (capital)
                return (char)baseKey;
            else
                return Char.ToLower((char)baseKey);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;  // not a letter
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but is your solutions includes KeyCode, KeyData ? Cuz they're not showing in KeyPress event except KeyChar.

Comment: @HashimAl-Mansouri `KeyPress` returns the *character* typed, not the key, so it doesn't provide key codes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to make the code too complicated, you can just add

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.[Key] && e.KeyCode != Keys.Capital)
 {
    //do whatever here
 }
```